# Replace any 0 value by interpolating it from the surrounding values of the 2D matrix

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D matrix of numbers separated by comma or space and read from a CSV file. Here's an example:

```
1,2,3
4,8,1
0 1 9
```

I already the whole process. But, I want to replace any 0 and compute the true value by interpolating it from the surrounding values, i.e., from the spatial neighbors of the entry in the matrix. Is there an efficient way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: If you have the matrix in memory, how you have read it is no longer relevant - unless you need to output the matrix somehow? In your example, what is the intended output? Is it `(1+4+8)/3`, `(1+4)/2`, or some other calculation?

Comment: The output is going to be the same as the input I mentioned above. The only difference is that when there's a zero I should replace it by interpolating it from the surrounding values of the matrix.

Comment: I have updated the description @tucuxi

Comment: You have not explained what the output should be to your input. There is a 0 in your example. Should it be replaced by `(1+4+8)/3` or by `(1+4)/2`? Are diagonally-adjacent numbers "spatially adjacent" or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below works (assuming you are only interested in vertically-and-horizontally-adjacent neighbors; and also assuming that you expect a zero surrounded by zeroes in the input to remain a zero in the output). Efficiency-wise, it can be improved -- but improvements comes with tradeoffs.

Improvements can be made to bounds-checking (all those if-statements), but this requires a certain cleverness. For example, you could do the edges separately, and then the whole central block would not require any bounds-checks at all. If you are not worried about the zeroes-affecting-other-zeroes problem, you could avoid creating a second array (which would gain in memory efficiency).

```js
function averageZeroes(a) {
  const rows = a.length;
  const cols = a[0].length;
  let b = [...Array(rows)].map(e => Array(cols))
  for (let r=0; r<rows; r++) {
    for (let c=0; c<cols; c++) {
      let v = a[r][c];
      if (v == 0) {
         let n = 0;
         if (r>0){
            n++; 
            v+=a[r-1][c];
         }
         if (r<rows-1) {
            n++; 
            v+=a[r+1][c];
         }
         if (c>0) {
            n++; 
            v+=a[r][c-1];
         }
         if (c<cols-1) {
            n++; 
            v+=a[r][c+1];
         }
         b[r][c] = v/n;
      } else {
         b[r][c] = a[r][c];
      }
    }
  }
  return b;
}

function test(a) {
  const p = (m) => JSON.stringify(m).replaceAll("],[","],\n [");
  console.log(p(a));
  console.log(p(averageZeroes(a)));
}

test(
[[1,2,3],
 [4,8,1],
 [0,1,9]])
```

Output:

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,8,1],
 [2.5,1,9]]
```

Comment: That's the same solution I thought of thank you tucuxi for the reply. I'd like to ask you why are you dividing the `value/n` that's the part I didn't understand because In my solution I just added all the values together and kept thinking this is not correct.

Comment: I asked several times, in comments, what type of interpolation you needed. You did not reply, so I provided sample code with what I think you probably need. Edit the question to explain what type of interpolation you are referring to. I am not using `value/n`, but rather `sum-of-values-of-neighbors / number-of-neighbors`

Comment: Yes, I see. I was thinking of a linear interpolation googled a little bit and I found out that it's kind of complicated a bit so I used the same solution you provided here.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it with a linear interpolation? just the formula.

Comment: good start but I dont think you have you considered the case where there are several zeros as neighbours. i think this should be extended and multiple passes should be made until there are no zeros left